# How to sort JavaScript Object with parent child tree

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have the following JavaScript Object structure.

```
[  
   [  
      null,
      "A"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "B"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "C"
   ],
   [  
      null,
      "D"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "E"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "F"
   ],
   [  
      "B",
      "G"
   ]
]
```

And I need to sorting it to be the following structure.

```
[
   {

      parent: "A",
      child : [
         {
            parent : "B",
            child : [
               {
                  parent : "G"
               }
            ]

         },
         {
            parent : "C"
         }
      ]

   },
   {

      parent: "D",
      child : [
         {
            parent : "E"

         },
         {
            parent : "F"

         }
      ]

   }
]
```

Comment: use recursion to solve this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add parents in result tree in straightforward way. But for adding children you will have to use recursion. Refer following solution.

```
var result_tree = [];
var test_data = [  
   [  
      null,
      "A"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "B"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "C"
   ],
   [  
      null,
      "D"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "E"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "F"
   ],
   [  
      "B",
      "G"
   ]
];

function create_tree(test_data) {
  test_data.forEach(function (node) {
    // create new root parent node if node does not have any parent
    if (node[0] === null) {
      result_tree.push(
        {
          parent: node[1],
        }
      )
    }
    // else search for existing parent and attach child to it
    else {
      search_and_attach_child(result_tree, node[0], node[1]);
    }
  });
}

function search_and_attach_child(tree, parent, child) {
  if (!tree) {
    return;
  }
  tree.forEach(function (node) {
    if (node.parent === parent) {
      if (node.child) {
        node.child.push({parent: child})
      } else {
        node.child = [{parent: child}]
      }
    } else {
      search_and_attach_child(node.child, parent, child);  
    }
  })
}

create_tree(test_data);
console.log(JSON.stringify(result_tree));
```

Comment: you can use `.some` and then return `true` when you have found a match, this will stop the iteration. (fake `break`)

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
var a = [  
   [  
      null,
      "A"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "B"
   ],
   [  
      "A",
      "C"
   ],
   [  
      null,
      "D"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "E"
   ],
   [  
      "D",
      "F"
   ],
   [  
      "B",
      "G"
   ]
];

var result = [];

for(var iter = 0; iter < a.length; iter++){

  var ele = a[iter];

  // element has no parent
  if(!ele[0] || !getParentByName(result,ele[0])){
    result.push({ parent: ele[1]});
  }
  // element has got parent
  else if(ele[0] && getParentByName(result,ele[0])){

    var parent = getParentByName(result,ele[0]);

    if(!parent.child)parent.child=[];

    parent.child.push({ parent: ele[1]});

  }



}

function getParentByName(result,name){

  for(var p=0; p <result.length;p++){

    if(result[p].parent == name)return result[p];

    for(var c=0; result[p].child && c <result[p].child.length;c++){
      if(result[p].child[c].parent == name)return getParentByName(result[p].child,name);
    }

  }

}

console.log(result);
```

Comment: your solution produces empty child array in result tree if a parent does not have a child. I think that is not required.

Comment: little feature removed ;)